# Do I need to always put base structs outside of the main() so they are globals?

Tags: struct, rust

I am working through the Rust documentation and having a hiccup on creating a struct with a function:

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("bob");
    let s2 = String::from("bob@aol.com");

    struct User {
        name: String,
        email: String,
    }

    let user1 = build_user(s1, s2); //or &s1, &s2
}

fn build_user(email: String, name: String) -> User {
    //or &String, &String
    User { email, name }
}
```

The error says:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `User` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:13:47
   |
13 | fn build_user(email: String, name: String) -> User {
   |                                               ^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0422]: cannot find struct, variant or union type `User` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     User { email, name }
   |     ^^^^ not found in this scope
```

If I want to build a struct with a function, do I have to pass the base struct as well by reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to always put them outside of *something*, but you do have to declare them at a high enough level so that everything that wants to use it can see it, visibility-wise.

By defining the type inside of the `main` function, only the body of the `main` function can access it. In this case, yes, you should put the definition of the struct outside of `main` because both `main` and `build_user` need to know of it:

```
struct User {
    name: String,
    email: String,
}

fn build_user(email: String, name: String) -> User {
    User { email, name }
}
```

As you read on, you will discover the idiomatic way of writing this code:

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("bob");
    let s2 = String::from("bob@aol.com");

    let user1 = User::new(s1, s2);
}

struct User {
    name: String,
    email: String,
}

impl User {
    fn new(email: String, name: String) -> User {
        User { email, name }
    }
}
```